# Trouble using appended audio

Tags: interface, audio

I tried appending an audio file from one Blender file to another and it appeared in the 'Sounds' part of the Blender file in the Outliner. The problem is I can find no way of actually using it. I can't drag it into the sequencer, nor can I copy it over. Could anyone suggest a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Set your outliner's display mode to `Blender File`, your audio files are in the `Sound` category, and you can drag'n'drop them in the video sequencer:

[image: demo picture]